# How can one filter out a day(DATEPART) from a DATETIME value while declaring variables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

```
DECLARE     @LatestFlightDate DATETIME, @LFDay INT

SET  @LatestFlightDate = (
              SELECT        MAX(FlightDateTime)
          FROM              dbo.Flight
                        )


SET   @LFDay = (    
    SELECT  DATEPART(DD, @LatestFlightDate)
    FROM    dbo.Flight
    )   
         )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @LatestFlightDate DATETIME, @LFDay INT

SELECT @LatestFlightDate = MAX(FlightDateTime) FROM dbo.Flight

SELECT @LFDay =  DATEPART(DD, @LatestFlightDate) FROM dbo.Flight
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get it using `DATEPART`

```
DECLARE @LFDay INT = (SELECT DATEPART(DAY,MAX(FlightDateTime)) FROM dbo.Flight)
```

OR

```
DECLARE @LFDay INT = (SELECT DAY(MAX(FlightDateTime)) FROM dbo.Flight)
```